# Indexing in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, indexing, r-tree

I have a table like below

```
CREATE TABLE `key_word` (
 `primary_key` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `indexVal` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hashed_word` char(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is how I am going to create the index for this.

```
ALTER TABLE key_word ADD INDEX (hashed_word, indexVal)
```

This creates a BTREE INDEX. But I am willing to build a RTree index, because I am doing a full text search. How can I create this index in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding R Trees are for spatial indexing.  The idea being that the R Tree allows you to find close values in a 2D plane quickly.   Have a look at the Mysql Geospatial reference documentation for more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

For full text search you can create fulltext index as per below:

```
ALTER TABLE key_word ADD FULLTEXT(hashed_word, indexVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

R-trees are not at all suitable for text. What made you think you need an Rtree index?

BTrees are good for sorted keys, but I figure you want to have substring search? Then use a `FULLTEXT` index maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The column I am going to search for will contain only 1 word per row. That word also a hash like `w1@`. What do you recommend now?